# Oracle. Constrain one row to have a certain value

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I want to add a constraint to a table where only one row can exist at any one time with a value in a certain column.

For example 
create table MyTable
 ....
    status varchar(1);
)

A check on status column would be 'O', 'C', 'P' for open , closed or pending.

There can be multiple Closed and Pending but only one (or none) row in the table can be Open.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Create a trigger that queries the table when a "O" is added to ensure that one doesn't already exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an unique function index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX myindex ON mytable( CASE status WHEN 'O' THEN 'O' END );
```

It will prevent from inserting two 'O' values, but will allow for other duplicate values.